# In extjs MVC architecture how to pass parameter to function

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I want to pass parameter "aaa" to disableFlied function, but the code below didn't work:

```
init: function() {

    this.control({
        '#speedCheck': {
            change :this.disableFlied("aaa")
        }
    });

},
disableFlied: function(cmpName){

    var a = Ext.getCmp(cmpName);
    a.setDisabled(!a.isDisabled());

}
```

How to pass "aaa" to disableFlied function?

Answer (score 5):

You must pass a function as event handler, here you're passing the result of calling `disableField` yourself (i.e. nothing since this method doesn't return anything). What you need to do is create another function that passes the desired parameter. In Ext, you can do that with the [`Ext.bind`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Function-method-bind) function.

Here's how you should use it:

```
this.control({
    '#speedCheck': {
        change: Ext.bind(this.disableField, this, ['aaa'])
    }
});
```

This will create a closure around the `disableField` method. This
is equivalent to this vanilla javascript code:

```
    '#speedCheck': {
        // This is the default scope, but I prefer to make it
        // explicit that the handler must be called in the
        // current scope
        scope: this
        ,change: function() {
            // When this function is called, it will call
            // disableField with the desired parameter
            this.disableField('aaa');
        }
    }
```

Comment: this.control({
    '#speedCheck': {
        change: Ext.bind(this.disableField, this, ['aaa'])
    }
this
});

Comment: If you have copy/pasted my example, notice that I have written `disableField`, while you in your code that's `disableFlied` with a typo.

Comment: If that still doesn't work, that probably indicates an error somewhere else in your code... You'll need to give more details to get further help. Starting by **how** it doesn't work.

Comment: I am new user of stackoverflow, not familiar with how to use it,just marked:)